# Merging associate arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have a serialized array stored in a cookie, at one point in my application I need to merge this array with another array with the same design, so:

Array 1:

```
$arr1 = array(
            "user_id" => 1,
            "item_id" => 2,
            "quant" => 3
        );
```

I set this in a cookie with:

```
serialize($arr1);
```

Array 2:

```
$arr2 = array(
            "user_id" => 5,
            "item_id" => 5,
            "quant" => 6
        );
```

My attempt at merging the two arrays:
First I unserialize the first array value that is in my cookie, followed by a merge with the second array

```
$un_arr1 = unserialize($cookie_val);
$final = array_merge($arr2, $un_arr1);
```

This is returning me only the values from the first array though.

What I am trying to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [item_id] => 2
            [quant] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 4
            [item_id] => 5
            [quant] => 6
        )
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$final = array($array1, $array2);`

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for [`array_merge_recursive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) instead of `array_merge`.

```
<?php

$A = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
$B = array('c' => 4, 'd'=> 5);

$result = array_merge_recursive($A, $B);

print_r($result);
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/Oewrb).